# Differential Equations and Eigenvectors/Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve $\dfrac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 &1\cr
-6 &1
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{x}$ and I need to find the general solution of the system in the form $x=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$.

Finding the eigenvalues, I have $\det(P - \lambda I) = 0 \implies \lambda = \dfrac{-5 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}$. But that can't be right since I'm going outside of the integers and into the irrationals and my vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ are supposed to be integer-valued vectors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must they be integers? This is a differential equation.

Comment: Fair enough. So if I understand then, I have to find the eigenvector corresponding to the matrix $\dfrac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
-4 +  \dfrac{5 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}&1\cr
-6 &1 + \dfrac{-5 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}
\end{array}\right] \mathbf{x}$ and find it using row-reduction. Is this right? Have I calculated the eigenvalue correctly?

Comment: I assume that you realize that what you "really" have is a set of _two_ differential equations of the form $\dot{x} = -4x + y$ and $\dot{y} = -6x + y$.  Which you solve by assuming $x = Ae^{rt}$ and $y = Be^{rt}$.  This will lead you to a linear set of equations which either give $x = y = 0$ or non-trivial solutions when the determinant is $0$ (i.e. the eigenvalues).

Comment: It turns out that you made a mistake in the calculation of the eigenvalues, which should be $-2$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Jared Yours might be a method. But one can directly see this as a Cauchy problem in $\mathbb R^2$ and use [this standard method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation) as well.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I agree with you that the matrix method is the "proper" way to solve.  My method breaks down (sort of--really it just becomes too complicated) when you have more functions (rather than just two).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I'll give the "dumb" way to do this--the way I used to do it in my Diff. EQ. class because I didn't understand eigenvalues or linear algebra at the time.  Assume you have the following:

$$
x = Ae^{rt} \\
y = Be^{rt}
$$

Plug in:

$$
\dot{x} = rAe^{rt} = -4Ae^{rt} + Be^{rt} \\
\dot{y} = rBe^{rt} = -6Ae^{rt} + Be^{rt}
$$

Now, we can factor out $e^{rt}$ because this is *never* zero (but even if it was, we could just set this equal to zero and factor out $e^{rt}$...so long as $e^{rt}$ is not identically zero), this gives:

$$
rA = -4A + B \\
rB = -6A + B
$$

Which leads to:

$$
0 = (-4 - r)A + B \\
0 = -6A + (1 - r)B
$$

Now, the "correct" way is to recognize that $r$ represents the eigenvalues of the original matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-4 & 1 \\ -6& 1\end{pmatrix}$ (i.e. by setting the above matrix's determinate to $0$).  But, hey, I didn't understand that at the time, so instead I simply solved for $B$ and then plugged into the second equation to find $r$ (or we could solve for $A$ and plug into the second equation or we could solve for $B$ in the second and plug into the first or we could solve for $A$ in the second and plug into the first...there isn't a "single" correct way to approach this):

$$
B = (4 + r)A \\
0 = -6A + (1 - r)(4 + r)A
$$

We can factor out $A$ to give:

$$
0 = -6 + (1 - r)(4 + r) = 0 \\
-6 + 4 - 3r - r^2 = 0 \\
r^2 + 3r + 2 = 0 \\
(r + 1)(r + 2) = 0
$$

This gives that $r = -1, -2$--two solutions.  The nice thing is that I *already* figured out what $B$ was in terms of $A$ and $r$ which means I get the general solution now:

$$
B_{-1} = (4 + -1)A = 3A \\
B_{-2} = (4 + -2)A = 2A
$$

Which finally leads to the general solution:

$$
x = A_1e^{-t} + A_2e^{-2t} \\
y = 3A_1e^{-t} + 2A_2e^{-2t}
$$

or

$$
\vec{x}(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A_1e^{-t} \\
A_2e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Dear Jared, I kid you not that is the most clear and concise answer to a question I have seen on Math Stack Exchange to any of the 50 or so questions I've asked on this site. Thanks for being awesome.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether Well just to be clear, you _should not_ solve these types of diff. eq.'s this way.  It works but it requires a lot of work.  If you can accept the whole eigenvalue/eigenvector way (perhaps see how this is equivalent) then you will have a much easier time.

Comment: Okay so given an initial condition $\mathbf{x}(0) = \left[\begin{array}{c}
3\cr
3
\end{array}\right]$, would I just have to calculate $\left[\begin{array}{c}
3\cr
3
\end{array}\right] = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\
A_2\end{pmatrix} $?

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think you messed up the eigenvalues.. If $A \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$, then $p_A(t) = t^2 - {\rm tr}(A)\,t + \det(A)$, so we have to solve: $$t^2 + 3t +2 = 0,$$which clearly has roots $-1$ and $-2$. Now you find eigenvectors $\bf v$ and $\bf w$, respectively. Your solution will be: $${\bf x} = e^{-t}{\bf v} + e^{-2t}{\bf w}.$$However, even if the eigenvalues weren't integers, you would do the same computations.

Comment: Wait. Isn't $(-4 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda) +6 = 0 \implies \lambda^2+5\lambda +2 = 0$?

Comment: Nope. $$-4+4\lambda - \lambda + \lambda^2 + 6 = \lambda^2 + 3\lambda + 2.$$

Comment: Wow you are totally right and I have totally not slept enough. Thank you very much.